# working out geoloction lat long

Tags: geolocation

Given a shape not just a circle or a square or triangle, but a shape with any number of edges, if the shape were to be drawn on a map how would I find if Lat long coordinates where within that shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) to the rescue. Describes solution in the Cartesian plane but that could be transferred to lat/long...